# getting error Missing required parameters for [Route: shortlist.update] [URI: recruiter/shortlistt/{id}/{jid}]

Tags: laravel

this is my view page route

```
<form method='post' action={{ route('shortlist.update', ['id' => $dd->jobseekers_unique_id, 'jid' => $dd->job_unique_id ]) }}>

{{ csrf_field() }}  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

<button type='submit' class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 btn btn-success">Shortlist</button>
</form>
```

and this my main route

```
Route::patch('shortlistt/{id}/{jid}','RecruiterController@shortlisted')->name('shortlist.update');
```

But it's giving me the error and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: how do you call your route in the view?[add full url call]

Comment: <form method="post" action={{ route('shortlist.update', ['id' => $dd->jobseekers_unique_id, 'jid' => $dd->job_unique_id ]) }} >

Comment: confirm these are  not empty `$dd->jobseekers_unique_id, 'jid` and `$dd->job_unique_id`

Comment: ya I checked it giving me the value like I used {{ $dd->jobseekers_unique_id}} {{ $dd->job_unique_id}} both these returning a value to view page.

Comment: add your routes file code

Comment: this is my route  Route::patch('shortlistt/{id}/{jid}','RecruiterController@shortlisted')->name('shortlist.update');

Comment: you get error on form rendering or form submission?

Comment: at rendering time when I refreshed a page it directly show error

Comment: Initially with one parameter it work correctly but when I add new parameter which  'jid' => $dd->job_unique_id it given me the error.

Comment: well the code doesn't create any problem in my testing. Please be sure that `$dd->jobseekers_unique_id` and `$dd->job_unique_id` have non empty value

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code, you missed the `quotes` for action. Here is your updated code.

```
<form method='post' action="{{ route('shortlist.update', ['id' => 

$dd->jobseekers_unique_id, 'jid' => $dd->job_unique_id ]) }}">

{{ csrf_field() }}  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

<button type='submit' class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 btn btn-success">Shortlist</button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried same as you given here <form method='post' action="{{ route('shortlist.update', ['id' => $dd->jobseekers_unique_id, 'jid' =>$dd->job_unique_id ]) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                            <button type='submit' class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 btn btn-success">Shortlist</button>
                    </form>

Comment: it showing same error again Missing required parameters for [Route: shortlist.update] [URI: recruiter/shortlistt/{id}/{jid}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rj\resources\views\recruiter\applied-candidates.blade.php)

Comment: this is my two route one for get and one for post Route::get('applied-candidates/{id}/','RecruiterController@appliedCandidates');
    Route::patch('shortlistt/{id}/{jid}','RecruiterController@shortlisted')->name('shortlist.update');

Comment: I think it taking the get route behalf of post route.